# .Net chromedriver.exe 2.36 has stopped working with chrome 64 couldnt fix

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Last year everything works ok, but when Ive tried to run program some days ago - got that annoying error: "chromedriver.exe has stopped working". And exception says: `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:59589/session/53a8deb4fccfe20b9b1636e3577a4eff/elements. The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure`

The driver doing first command - navigation to url, but when I am trying to get some elements from driver - got that error.

I got latest Chrome 64.0.3282.186, chromedriver 2.36.0 and webdriver 3.10.00 nuget packages.

When I downgraded browser to 61.0 - everything works just fine. 
I got arguments:

```
opt.AddArgument("start-maximized");
opt.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
opt.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
opt.AddArgument("--mute-audio");

opt.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features");
opt.AddArgument("--disable-app-list-dismiss-on-blur");
opt.AddArgument("--disable-core-animation-plugins");
```

commenting it doesnt changed anything.

How could I fix that odd issues?

Comment: IMO `chromedriver 2.36` is still in alpha/beta definitely not a **GA** version. Better to pick up **chromedriver 2.35**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the webdriver and nuget package then install it again.

Important that you install these in this order:

1. Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver
2. Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats solve a situation. Problem was that in startup project there was no reference to that packages.

Comment: No problem, yeah i know. Scratched my head a few time about this, not understanding what the problem was. :)